# Dockerizing an SSH Daemon Service using my own key

Tags: vagrant, docker, vagrantfile

I am building an image based on ubuntu14.04, try to enable ssh on the container. I am following the tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/

But this tutorial only shows how to ssh using password, I want to use my own key to ssh into container instead of password. So I can do something like this in the vagrantfile (Docker as a provider, and using ansible to provision):

```
  config.ssh.username = "root"
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/my_key"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also.

Unfortunately I don't have a simple answer, but use a standard ShutIt library for this:

https://github.com/ianmiell/shutit/blob/master/library/ssh_key/ssh_key.py

which copies ssh keys to the host as it's building.

It doesn't show up in the image history either, so you don't need to flatten images; and you can remove it (default, but configurable) at the end of the build using the ssh_key module's finalize hook.

allows me to combine this with other modules as I need it. For example, it's depended on by the ansible module, for example:

https://github.com/ianmiell/shutit/blob/master/library/ansible/ansible.py#L64

and the library/puppet.py and library/hadoop/hadoop.py:

If you need help with it contact me directly.

Comment: I'm only working with Dockerfile and Vagrantfile, also yml for ansible. No python involved. What changes needed for Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to ssh?

Be aware of the **very significant reasons** for not doing it:
http://blog.docker.com/2014/06/why-you-dont-need-to-run-sshd-in-docker/

You can also as of docker v1.3 just inject new processes into running containers..
e.g. if you can ssh onto the host, then 
docker exec -it myContainer /bin/bash

will attach a terminal to your running container...

But you can look at one I cooked up earlier... https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/afolarin/ubuntu_ssh/

Comment: I am provisioning using ansible, which requires ssh to the container.